# How to set static IP via script on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, server, 18.04

I am in the process of setting up a new Ubuntu 18.04 Server template for our virtual environment, and as part of this I have a script I created and have used on previous versions.

All it does is ask for the host name, IP settings and NTP server to use. It then sets the host name with `hostnamectl`, adds the name to the hosts file, sets the NTP server with `ntpdate`, writes out the IP info to `/etc/network/interfaces`, downloads all updates, applies them and reboots.

This script won't work in 18.04 as the way you set static IPs has changed by quite a bit. So how do I set a static IP/Netmask/DNS/Gateway programmatically?

EDIT: So this install of 18.04 has Cloudinit installed by default, and that is what has thrown me for a loop here. So I am going to download the other ISO and use that instead.

But to simplify my question, is there a CLI tool that I can install that does this for me in a simple command. EG `cli-tool <IP> <SUBNET> <GATEWAY> <DNS1> <DNS2>` ?

Answer (score 0):

**18.04** use **netplan**. Have a look at its [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/netplan.5.html)

You can make your script write a `.yaml` file in `/etc/netplan` and "compile" it with `netplan apply` or `netplan try` or `netplan generate`

One example of such a file would be:

```
ethernets:
  match:
    name: enp2s0
      addresses: [10.0.4.5/8]
      gateway4: 10.0.4.1
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 1.1.1.1, 9.9.9.9]
        search: [mycompany]
```

I am not very familiar with *netplan*. So I let you explore and fix my possible errors.

Comment: From what I could get from Google this *might* work, however there is no real info that I could find about `cloud-init` which appears to be setup by default on a 18.04 install. The .yaml file even goes as far as to say that if you change it, it won't stick.

I was really hoping there was a CLI command that could just do it (eg `cli-command 192.168.2.98/24 192.168.2.1 ns1 ns2 ...`

Comment: Well, this is not what you asked;. rephrase your question. https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/network-config-format-v2.html?highlight=netplan

Answer (score 0):

@solsTiCe is correct, however `/etc/network/interfaces` is still a valid method for configuring the network.

`man interfaces`

There's also the `/etc/NetworkManager` route, by the way.

`man NetworkManager.conf`

In actual fact, `netplan` *renders to* NetworkManager.  So it's really just syntactic sugar for NetworkManager and Systemd.

[More on `netplan` here](https://netplan.io/).